# JMeter : Client certificate issue

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, keytool, client-certificates

I am facing issue with the execution of the APIs in Jmeter.
I have multiple .keys files**(includes .crt and .key files)** where i need to use .keys file in HTTP calls and In jmeter I have created a csv file to pick up the created alias but by default its fetching the first certs for all the HTTP calls.

and also used the below setting in the file.
https.keyStoreStartIndex=1
https.keyStoreEndIndex=4

Can you please help me with the integration of our client certificate with the Jmeter.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

1. First you need to [import your certificates into keystore](https://www.baeldung.com/java-import-cer-certificate-into-keystore) and give each certificate its own alias.
2. Second you need to point JMeter to the keystore via `javax.net.ssl.keyStore` property and supply the password via `javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword` property
3. Then put all the aliases to the CSV file and add [CSV Data Set Config](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config) pointing to that file
4. And finally add [Keystore Configuration](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Keystore_Configuration) element and use the variable from step 4 there

More information: [How to Use Multiple Certificates When Load Testing Secure Websites](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-use-multiple-certificates-when-load-testing-secure-websites)